# Where is RSA applied in real life?

Tags: encryption, rsa, elliptic-curves

For instance, I know that the BlackBerry uses a form of ECC built-in for data protection.

But would like to know if either the iPhone or Android smartphones, for instance, use a form of RSA?

If RSA is not implemented in any modern smartphones, then I would like to know any commonly used technological devices where RSA is used in real life?

Thank you.

Comment: Android smartphones that meet Google's security certification use hardware-based RSA keys to make encryption more secure.

Comment: Thanks, Melab. Do you know any link to read more about this?

Comment: "BlackBerry uses a form of ECC built-in for data protection". I think you might be mixing up Error-Correcting Code memory and Elliptic Curve Cryptography.

Comment: @AgentME Thank you so much for clearing the RSA question I had. You're a savior man! By the way, I got the ECC and BlackBerry information by a lecturer on youtube and this link? I probably misunderstood it tho: https://n4bb.com/blackberrys-potential-biggest-patent-asset-elliptic-curve-cryptography/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RSA is one of the cipher suites used in Transport Layer Security, which is used by HTTPS, so RSA may be used in any connection to an https: URL. (Elliptic Curve Cryptography may also be used in TLS/HTTPS in the same way.)

Asymmetric cryptography (either RSA or ECC) is usually used in a lot of software for verifying that software updates are from the original developer.

Comment: Do you know use cases when it's used for _encryption_ as opposed to signatures?